# How to set cookie domain and path with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jsessionid

In Tomcat, we can do it like this:

```
<Context useHttpOnly="true" sessionCookiePath="/"sessionCookieDomain=".XXXX.com"/>
```

I want to share the cookie for second level domain with Spring Boot, how to do it?

Answer (score 20):

Settings for the server that Spring Boot embeds are available as application properties ([listed here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) under the section `# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION` and the namespace `server.servlet.session.cookie.*`).

The equivalent to the Tomcat config from above should be:

```
# properties in /src/resources/application.properties
server.servlet.session.cookie.domain=.XXXX.com
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.path=/
```

Comment: forgot to add `servlet` between server and session

Comment: Ozzy's right. It should be server.servlet.session.cookie.domain according to the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: I had to implement following for spring boot 2+ to make it work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39196298/716027

Answer (score 2):

(This applies to Spring 1.5.x at the time of this writing)

To add to @radrocket81's reply, here's an example code. Also this is how you set the max-age and other properties of Spring boot cookies **if you enabled Redis session by @EnableRedisHttpSession** as application property server.session won't be applied.

```java
@Bean
public <S extends ExpiringSession> SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends ExpiringSession> springSessionRepositoryFilter(SessionRepository<S> sessionRepository, ServletContext servletContext) {
    SessionRepositoryFilter<S> sessionRepositoryFilter = new SessionRepositoryFilter<S>(sessionRepository);
    sessionRepositoryFilter.setServletContext(servletContext);
    CookieHttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy = new CookieHttpSessionStrategy();
    httpSessionStrategy.setCookieSerializer(this.cookieSerializer());
    sessionRepositoryFilter.setHttpSessionStrategy(httpSessionStrategy);
    return sessionRepositoryFilter;
}

private CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setCookieName("CUSTOM_SESSION_KEY");
    serializer.setDomainName("domain.com");
    serializer.setCookiePath("/");
    serializer.setCookieMaxAge(10); //Set the cookie max age in seconds, e.g. 10 seconds
    return serializer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to define a CookieSerializer bean and provide the domain pattern that fits my setup.

Like this: [Spring Session - Custom Cookie](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.0.M2/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html#custom-cookie-sample)