# Error with cookie-value when adding a new Spring Session

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-session

In my `Spring Boot` 1.4 based application I use `Spring Session` to store session data in the database with `JDBC`.

This works fine with the default session. But when I want to add a new session (by adding `?_s=1` to the application url) I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [32] was present in the Cookie value
```

What is the issue here?

*Edit: Note that I do not set the cookie value myself, `Spring Session` does that. Thus I can not tell which value it tries to set.*

The complete stacktrace is here:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [32] was present in the Cookie value
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.validateCookieValue(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:160) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.generateHeader(Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.generateCookieString(Response.java:989) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookie(Response.java:937) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addCookie(ResponseFacade.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer.writeCookieValue(DefaultCookieSerializer.java:112) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy.onNewSession(CookieHttpSessionStrategy.java:213) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:247) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:214) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper.onResponseCommitted(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:202) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.doOnResponseCommitted(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:226) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:126) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse.sendRedirect(FirewalledResponse.java:41) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:128) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:138) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:128) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy.sendRedirect(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:57) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:204) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80) ~[spring-session-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
```

Comment: What is the value you are trying to set on the cookie?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Control character in cookie value or attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109318/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-control-character-in-cookie-value-or-attribu)

Comment: I don't know which value Spring Session wants to set in the cookie.

Comment: You can inspect the value of cookie Spring Session attempts to write by placing a breakpoint at `DefaultCookieSerializer.java:112` (which is the 6th line from your stackrace).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is due to Tomcat's cookie processing being changed to a RFC 6265 compliant implementation by default in 8.5, which does not allow space (character 32), among others.

As a workaround, you can configure Tomcat to use legacy cookie processor. To do this with Spring Boot, register an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` `@Bean` like this:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizer() {
    return container -> {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
            tomcat.addContextCustomizers(context -> context.setCookieProcessor(new LegacyCookieProcessor()));
        }
    };
}
```

Also see [spring-projects/spring-session#gh-605](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/605) to track the progress of fixing this in Spring Session.

Update:

The above described solution is valid for Spring Boot 1.x. Starting with Spring Boot 2.0, `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` has been replaced with `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` as described in the [Spring Boot 2.0 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#embedded-containers-package-structure).

Also note that starting with Spring Session 2.0, session cookie is Base64 encoded by default which prevents the original problem from occurring.

Comment: how to handle '=' in Cookie (Base 64 encoded) ? Legacy fails for cookie parsing.

Comment: Hi there, what are the options for Spring 2.* ? There are no `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` on its dependencies. Thanks.

Comment: @JorgeCampos The `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` has been renamed to `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` in Spring Boot 2.0. Please refer to [Spring Boot 2.0 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#embedded-containers-package-structure).

Comment: Thank Vedran. Appreciated. Cheers,

Comment: Spring Boot 2 version - https://gist.github.com/fedotxxl/10ff957c40bd166717d6c177ed14f92d

Answer (score 15):

Function cookie cannot encode properly the value with space also french signs and so on. I solve this problem with **URLEncoder.encode(String arg0, Encoding version)** here I used UTF-8.
Here the method I created!

```
private static void setCookie( HttpServletResponse response, String nom, String valeur, int maxAge )throws IOException { 
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie( nom, URLEncoder.encode( valeur, "UTF-8" ) );
    cookie.setMaxAge( maxAge );
    response.addCookie( cookie );
}
```

Comment: it's better that we should add a single line of code in the context file as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702343/7515186

Comment: @SyedZeeshanAli No, we shouldn't use outdated code. Nobody should ever use `*Legacy*CookieProcessor` ever, if that could be avoided. Nobody should write new code that is already deprecated right from the start!

Answer (score 14):

CookieProcessor is a new configuration element, introduced in Tomcat 8.0.15. The CookieProcessor element allows different cookie parsing configuration in each web application, or globally in the default conf/context.xml file.

According to official docs at [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference Version 8.0.47](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/cookie-processor.html) :

**The standard implementation of CookieProcessor is: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor. Note that it is anticipated that this will change to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor in a future Tomcat 8 release.**

Later..

According to official docs at [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference Version 8.5.23:](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/cookie-processor.html)

**The standard implementation of CookieProcessor is org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor.**

To resolve this issue: add this line in conf/context.xml at location %CATALINA_HOME% (i.e. C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\conf\context.xml in my case):

```
<CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor" />
```

This is how it looks like after adding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context reloadable="true">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Transaction factory="bitronix.tm.BitronixUserTransactionObjectFactory"/>
    <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor" />    
</Context>
```

Answer (score 2):

we can apply cookieValue.trim() or cookieValue.replace(" ", "") to remove whitespaces 
 or "spcbefore

Answer (score -1):

Don't use whitespaces in the content of the cookie. It is mentioning whitespace as the invalid character.

Comment: Answer in proper way so that others can understand.

Comment: I'm new in Stack Overflow, so I know the answer I posted but how to add the code that I don't know.