# Use LegacyCookieProcessor without Spring Boot or context.xml on the server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cookies

I recently upgraded a project to Java 8, targeting Tomcat 9. It relies heavily on cookies that use commas and possibly spaces in the value so I need to use `LegacyCookieProcessor` because the cookies aren't RFC 6265 compliant. The only two ways I can find on how to do this [require Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687210/error-with-cookie-value-when-adding-a-new-spring-session) or [editing `context.xml` in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696081/how-to-change-cookie-processor-to-legacycookieprocessor-in-tomcat-8). This project isn't using Spring Boot so the first one isn't an option, and I'd really rather not break portability by requiring `context.xml` to be changed wherever it is deployed.

Is it possible to configure this in Java config or web.xml (or any other way)?

Comment: from my understanding, tomcat supports per application config in [`/META-INF/context.xml`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) bundled in the application package just like `web.xml` - and that file should support the cookie processor config.

Comment: @zapl Thank you, this worked. Feel free to post this solution as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Done. Feel free to edit the answer if you have anything useful to add / correct, I have never touched a tomcat config myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat supports per application config in [`/META-INF/context.xml`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) bundled in the application package just like the `web.xml` file.

That file supports the cookie processor config

```
<CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor" />
```