# Sending private key to the cookie

Tags: java, cookies

I have generated a private key using below function -

```
public static String getPrivateKey() {

        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
         KeyPair keyPair = null;
        try {
            keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString( keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
```

I am trying to set this to my cookie using below-

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("privatekey", privateKey);// creating cookie object
            ck.setMaxAge(120);
            response.addCookie(ck);// adding cookie in the response
```

I am getting below error. The key is in string format itself. How can I do this? Do I need to change it to some format?

```
An invalid character [13] was present in the Cookie value
```

My private key generated looks like below-

```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```

Comment: Did you try removing `=`?

Comment: Yep . didn't work

Comment: You should specify the Java container (tomcat I guess). Try `URLEncoder.encode(privateKey, "UTF-8" )`. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687210/error-with-cookie-value-when-adding-a-new-spring-session